# SharePoint 2010 site slow at first load

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, warm-up

I have a web application which had been created 4 months ago with a custom template, but from about 3 weeks ago this web application is very slow at first load. 90 secondes+ After the first load it loads quickly, about 1 sec.

The **warmup script** was added to the server. All web applications works fine except this one.

I don't know how to check this error. How I can get more information?

Is any solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: What warmup script did you use? Is this script part of a third party solution?

Comment: You can try enabling developer dashboard and see which request is taking more time.

Comment: @TempaC Yes, warmup is a third party solution

Comment: @AmalHashim, thank you, if I check the ULS log, is it possible find the request which is taking more time?

Comment: @MKQian I am not sure. You can try that also. Also check the SQL side, like diskspace/processor etc.

Comment: @AmalHashim, hello, if the site uses the custom master page, is it possible hide developer Dashboard? My colleague said that he had clicked the **developer Dashboard icon**, but he had not seen the **developer Dashboard** at the bottom of the page